# Git Track Branch

Tags: git

I have a repository with one branch called testing and on the server I want to have 2 separate folders - one that pulls from the master branch (git pull origin master) and the other pulls from the testing branch (git pull origin testing ? )

Whats the best way to set this up - I tried this and got an error saying that the remote branch is not tracked. I am pretty new to git so not really sure how to set this up?

The idea is to work on the testing branch and then once a week merge it into the master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want two clones of the repository on the server, one setup to track your local master branch, and the other your local testing branch?

On the server, clone your repo and rename the directory *master*. This will be your *master* directory, and it's already configured to fetch and merge from `origin/master` on a pull

Next, make a copy of the *master* directory called *testing*. In that directory, create a branch called `testing` and tell it to track `origin/testing`:

```
git branch --track testing origin/testing
git checkout testing
```

That should be it. The *master* and *testing* directories will fetch and merge `origin/master` and `origin/testing` respectively.

Comment: yes that's what I want to do. So instead of making a cope of the master directory , I simply created new blank folder and git cloned into that one as well. Is that why I could not get it working?

Comment: @Jimmy Whether you make a second directory by cloning twice or cloning and copying, the result will be identical. Clone-and-copy is simply faster.